# Duration calculation between two date fields

Tags: formula, cpq, pricerule

I have two date fields start date &End date. I want to calculate the duration between these two fields in the no.of months with a formula for a Price action salesforce CPQ.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Please review this discussion for your requirement - [How to calculate duration between two dates(in months and days) using formula field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132961/how-to-calculate-duration-between-two-datesin-months-and-days-using-formula-fi) .

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [Edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: I have tried (End_Date - Start_Date). But I want it in exact no of months

Answer (score 0):

MONTH(start_date__c) + 12 * (YEAR(end_date__c) - YEAR(start_date__c)) - MONTH(end_date__c)

Here's an explanation of the formula:

1. MONTH(start_date__c) calculates the month value of the start date.
2. YEAR(end_date__c) - YEAR(start_date__c) calculates the difference in
   years between the end date and the start date.
3. 12 *
   (YEAR(end_date__c) - YEAR(start_date__c)) calculates the number of
   months based on the difference in years.
4. - MONTH(end_date__c) subtracts the month value of the end date.

This formula will give you the duration in the number of months
between    the start date and end date. You can use this formula in a Price
action in Salesforce CPQ to calculate the desired duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this formula for better validation on this :

```
IF(ISBLANK(StartDate_c) || ISBLANK(EndDate_c), null,
    (YEAR(EndDate_c) - YEAR(StartDate_c)) * 12 +
    MONTH(EndDate_c) - MONTH(StartDate_c) +
    IF(DAY(EndDate_c) < DAY(StartDate_c), -1, 0)
)
```

Or you can also use :

```
MONTH(end_date) - MONTH(start_date) + 12 * (YEAR(end_date) - YEAR(start_date))
```

for the same.

Hope this helps !